# Comparing two quantities

Tags: graphing-functions, dimensional-analysis

So I have two agents that have strategies, each of which are specified via one parameter. For agent1 its p and agent2 its q. Each of these agents produce a payoff p1 and p2, which depend on the interactions between them.

I want to find how p1 and p2 would vary with respect to the change in the input strategy parameters. So if I was trying to graph it in 3-D ,with p and q as two axes, is there a way for me to model some f(p1,p2) as the third axes that would give me insight into their behavior wrt each other.

At the moment I'm simply plotting their ratio. I'm not sure what the best metric would be.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't think I would use $p,q$ as the two axes. Use your strategy parameters as axes and plot on different graphs $p-q$ and $p/q$, perhaps this should give some intuition.